# C# class variable initialization

Tags: c#, private, declaration, public

I want to declare and initialize a string variable that is local to a class but can be accessed by all functions of the class. Fyi, this is an app for a gui which will be making use of several text files in folders. I am trying to set a string variable containing the project directory path so it can be accessed by all the functions within this class.

I have provided an portion of my code including the function that sets the path along with a function that uses the string variable when set.

```
public class Program
{   
    private string DirectoryPath;

    public static void Main()
    {
        setPaths();
        SetGroundTempArray();
    }

    public static void setPaths()
    {
        DirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }

    public static void SetGroundTempArray()
    {
        string groundtempfile = "\\groundtemp.txt";
        string groundtempdir = "\\Text Files";
        string groundtempFP = DirectoryPath + groundtempdir + groundtempfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't compile.
You should declare the `DirectoryPath` class field as static:

```
private static string DirectoryPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are currently on the right track. In C# we call them [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Fields typically store the data that must be accessible to more than
>   one class method and must be stored for longer than the lifetime of
>   any single method

In your case  `private string DirectoryPath;` is a field. And you are following the good practice of making it `private`.

Also as noted you have all methods as `static` so you need to make the Field variable `static` as well to access it

```
private static string DirectoryPath;
```

> A field can optionally be declared static. This makes the field
>   available to callers at any time, even if no instance of the class
>   exists.

Answer (score 1):

As given in your example, you have done it right as the functionality you want. But you may need to learn more about the usage of `static` keywords in C#. You can learn more about it at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Here's a intercept about your code, that might clear your concept.
As `DirectoryPath` is used by a static method in your progream, you must need to declare this variable as `static` also because of, `setPaths` method is used in static Main, and Main is the topmost level static class that don't requires the instance to be created of the `Program` Class. and that is why, `Main` method would require all the methods or variable or fields is being used inside the method must be declared as static.

```
public class Program
{   
    private static string DirectoryPath;

    public static void Main()
    {
        setPaths();
        SetGroundTempArray();
    }

    public static void setPaths()
    {
        DirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }

    public static void SetGroundTempArray()
    {
        string groundtempfile = "\\groundtemp.txt";
        string groundtempdir = "\\Text Files";
        string groundtempFP = DirectoryPath + groundtempdir + groundtempfile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add static in front of string.

```
 class Program
{
    //add static in front of string
    static String a = "Hello";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        h();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void h()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }


}
```